# Delete button with alert does not work in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete, delete-row

If I click the delete button, then it is asking permission from me to delete the contents but after clicking, `OK` contents are not deleting.

In my understanding, my code can not catch the **id** to delete the contents.

In my browser search box it is showing :

**localhost/new/tree1/view_tree.php?id=**

For getting the **id** code is given below:

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM descriptionoftree WHERE vis=0 order by scientificname");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td >'.$row['scientificname'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['english_name'].'</div></td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['banglaname'].'</div></td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['groupname'].'</div></td>';
            echo '<td><a href="update_tree.php? id='.$row['id'].'" title="Click To Update"><strong>Update</strong></a></td>';
 ?>
    <td><a href="view_tree.php?id=<?php $row['id']?>
     "onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"<strong>Delete </strong></a></td>
    <?php
        echo '</tr>';
        }   
        ?>
```

For deleting the **row (contents)** code is given below:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
   {
     $cid=$_GET['id'];
     $sql=mysql_query("DELETE descriptionoftree WHERE id='$cid'");
   }
```

Comment: If you are expecting PHP to respond to a JavaScript alert, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: add echo in <a href="view_tree.php?id=<?php $row['id']?> //<?php echo $row['id']?>

Comment: @durbnpoisn There is nothing wrong with what he did. I did it and it works.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: @ tadman Thank's for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not echoing your variable here.

```
                                   vvv
<td><a href="view_tree.php?id=<?php $row['id']?>
```

Add an echo

```
<td><a href="view_tree.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>
```

Or use short echo tag

```
<td><a href="view_tree.php?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>
```

Also, your delete query is wrong. You're missing `FROM`.

Should be this:

```
$sql=mysql_query("DELETE FROM descriptionoftree WHERE id='$cid'");
```

Also try reading up on SQL Injections, [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Your current code is vulnerable.

Comment: It is being echoed by the outer echo. Its concatenated

Comment: What outer echo? This is HTML before the tag, not an echo.

Comment: that isn't all that's wrong with that guy's code. that delete will never happen. Edit: where you added it.

Comment: Guess you tought I was talking about the first line with `$row['id']` XD

Answer (score 0):

You forgot make **echo** of your $row['id'] change this line:

```
<td><a href="view_tree.php?id=<?php $row['id']?>
     "onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"<strong>Delete </strong></a></td>
```

For

```
<td><a href="view_tree.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>
     "onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"<strong>Delete </strong></a></td>
```

and your sql for delete the row is bad, same, your have a sintaxis error, missing the word **FROM**, update this line:

```
$sql=mysql_query("DELETE descriptionoftree WHERE id='$cid'");
```

For

```
$sql=mysql_query("DELETE FROM descriptionoftree WHERE id='$cid'");
```

And test it

Regards